# How can i add multiple images to my scrollView in ios

Tags: ios

i have scroll View with three slides,i want to add images to my scroll view.this is my code after this what do i need to add

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
[scroll addSubview:awesomeView];
[awesomeView release];
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[scroll release];
}
```

Comment: Add the images to each one of the slides.

Comment: i am new to IOS.pls..post how to add images to 3 slides..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add Images horizontally (say 3 images), than you have to add scroll view with the width of 3*yourImageView.frame.size.width and than you can add those Image on (x=0,y=0),
(x = `yourImageView.frame.size.width`, y=0), and  (x = `2*yourImageView.frame.size.width`, y=0)

```
    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, yourImageView.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
    imageView1.frame = CGrectMake(0,0,imageView1.frame.size.width,imageView1.frame.size.height);
imageView2.frame = CGrectMake(0,imageView1.frame.size.width,imageView2.frame.size.width,imageView2.frame.size.height)
imageView3.frame = CGrectMake(0,2*imageView1.frame.size.width,imageView3.frame.size.width,imageView3.frame.size.height)

    [scroll addSubview:imageView1];
    [scroll addSubview:imageView2];
    [scroll addSubview:imageView3];
```

**enable horizontal scrolling**